# Which page range do you cite in an article in IEEE proceedings?

Tags: publications, citations, ieee

In biblatex I have cited using `@inproceedings` with `pages={3310--3317}`. I myself only used a pdf of the article, which does not contain page numbers. Since I cite the article directly and not the book, do I cite the page range 1-7 or 3310-3317 in the text itself?

Comment: You cite in such a way that somebody else can actually find the article. Since it is in a proceedings volume, one would use that actual numbers used in the proceedings.

Answer (score 1):

If the proceedings actually have page numbers, cite the page range in which the article appears.

However, it is becoming more and more common for many conferences to not have bundled proceedings with page numbers (also in electronic form), and so all the articles have no page numbers or they have the same fictitious page numbers (e.g. with starting page 1 for all the articles). In this case, page numbers don't matter, but the reader should be able to locate the article: therefore, whether you don't put any page range or you put the fictitious one, try to add other identifiers like the DOI, if supported. This is especially important if there are two version of the article with the same title, a short one published in the proceedings and an extended one published in a journal.

Comment: Ok, I see. Very interesting. I myself use the online PDFs, which do not have page numbers. But I am not able to find DOIs for those, as all citations show them in the Proceedings. So I'll stick to using the real numbers